# No Library assets showing in old job running in 3.6.4

Tags: library

I have an older archvis job I have been working on and off for a long time. The job was created in older versions but for some reason, this file does not show any of the assets in the asset library - not even the built in "essentials Hair" shows up. At one point it did see assets but in recent updates, something became unglued. Any new job I start works fine, everything shows. The file paths are correct in all instances yet that particular job just will not connect to the library. I'm guessing this may be a datablock issue but just don't know. Is there a way to clean that up in the job so the link to the library is working? I've tried reinstalling 3.6.4 and setting it to "repair" and it seemed to find a file missing or corrupted but that didn't fix the issue.

One addition - I just opened a new job, appended all the collections and materials from the old job and the library function works in the new job so, is there a way to reindex, or clean up the data in the original job?